# Instantiation of Play! Action - what language construction is that?

Tags: scala

What language construction is used here to create Action instance? I thought that in Scala it is possible to instantiate a class using:

- Direct constructor call: `new Action(params)`
- Call `apply()` method of companion object (which usually calls constructor): `Action(params)`

But in the Scaladoc of Play! Action is see following snippet:

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

What is called here? I understand that we create function `request => response`, but where is this function passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is equivalent to this:

```
val echo = Action.apply(request => Ok("Got request [" + request + "]"))
```

So you're actually calling object `Action`'s `apply` method and pass it an anonymous function.

Be aware that in Scala, you can mostly interchange parentheses and braces, so e.g. if you have this function

```
def f(a: Int) = a + 42
```

these calls are equivalent:

```
f(23)
f { 23 }
```

The next thing that happens is that you can omit the name of the `apply` method. So if you have an object like this:

```
object f { def apply(a: Int) = a + 42 }
```

these calls are all equivalent:

```
f.apply(23)
f.apply { 23 }
f(23)
f { 23 }
f apply 23
f apply { 23 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are calling the Action companion object's apply method.  And as Andreas pointed out during method calls () can be replaced by {} AFAIK.

api doc [Action object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action%24)

```
def apply(block: (Request[AnyContent]) ⇒ Result): Action[AnyContent]
```

Action is a subclass of ActionBuilder. It goes to [this method](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L236) call in the play frame work source code.

Answer (score 0):

To all said above, for you also would be useful to CTRL + click on the class/method name in your IDE and look in the source code. That sometimes clarifies a lot.
Please try and you will see 3 or 4 different variants of apply() methods in the ActionBuilder class.